# WYSIWYG tool for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: software-development, web-development, css, wysiwyg, asp.net

I am a backend software engineer, but I am also a big fan of UI. My primary language is C#. I know CSS and HTML5, but I'm not strong on layout. For example, if I use ASP.net MVC 4 to create a default web project and I want to move the log on part to another place, I have to take a very long time to adjust the front end code. Of course the color and the layout is still ugly.

So I want a tool that is sort of WYSIWYG to move a component from one place to another very easily. This tool should work with ASP.net MVC.

Comment: Visual Studio does have a built in WYSIWYG editor, but personally I find it easier and more reliable to edit the markup directly.

Comment: That is for asp.net web forms rather than asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is frankly no good answer, because whichever tool you end up using will invariably mess up the code under it. I have not seen a single tool released in the past 14 years that was able to generate markup that could be considered acceptable.

In addition, most WYSIWYG editors are completely incapable of generating markup/CSS that works across browsers, especially with mobile devices entering the market.

Your real options here are to learn CSS or to find someone to handle that job. I am aware that this is not the answer you are looking for, but there is no software that will do what you want properly.

Comment: Addition for future readers: this is strictly speaking about WYSIWYG editors that handle layout. If you are only looking for a rich text editor for page content or documents, then TinyMCE will do the job marvelously, and you can configure it to generate very good markup.